# Align labels and inputs in nested elements

Tags: css, layout

Semantically, my data is structured something like the following:

```html
<div class="inputs">
    <div class="top">
        <h4>Top</h4>

        <label for="top-1">Label 1</label>
        <input id="top-1"/>

        <label for="top-2">Label 2 is longer than the others</label>
        <input id="top-2"/>
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        <h4>Middle</h4>

        <label for="middle-1">Label 3</label>
        <select id="middle-1">
            <option value="middle-value-1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="middle-value-2" selected>This is a longer value</option>
        </select>

        <label for="middle-2">Label 4</label>
        <input id="middle-2"/>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
        <h4>Bottom</h4>

        <label for="bottom-1">Label 5</label>
        <input id="bottom-1"/>

        <label for="bottom-2">Label 6</label>
        <input id="bottom-2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to display these as distinct but related groups.  For aesthetic purposes, I'd like to align and equally size all of the inputs and selects.  Is it possible to do this without using explicit widths for everything?  I greatly prefer to let things size themselves whenever possible.

Below is an implementation using `display: grid` with fixed widths for the columns and the grid itself.  Is there any way to do this with dynamic sizes?

I'm not stuck on `display: grid`, by the way.  It's just the simplest solution I've come up with so far.  I like that it helps keep my HTML simple and semantic.  I can use `display: table` just as well if I nest the labels and inputs in a `div` with `display: table-row`.  But I still can't let things size dynamically, unless I flatten it by removing the `top`, `middle`, and `bottom` divs.

```css
.inputs > div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 13em 10em;
    width: 24em;
    gap: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.inputs label {
    grid-column: 1;
}

.inputs select, .inputs input {
    grid-column: 2;
}

.inputs h4 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    margin: 0;
}

.top, .bottom {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.middle {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.middle, .bottom {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
    <div class="top">
        <h4>Top</h4>

        <label for="top-1">Label 1</label>
        <input id="top-1"/>

        <label for="top-2">Label 2 is longer than the others</label>
        <input id="top-2"/>
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        <h4>Middle</h4>

        <label for="middle-1">Label 3</label>
        <select id="middle-1">
            <option value="middle-value-1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="middle-value-2" selected>This is a longer value</option>
        </select>

        <label for="middle-2">Label 4</label>
        <input id="middle-2"/>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
        <h4>Bottom</h4>

        <label for="bottom-1">Label 5</label>
        <input id="bottom-1"/>

        <label for="bottom-2">Label 6</label>
        <input id="bottom-2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with `display: table`.  It's a little uglier than the grid solution and not quite as semantic as I'd like, but it's close, and it does what I want.

```css
.inputs {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.inputs > .top, .inputs > .bottom {
    display: table-row-group;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.inputs > .middle {
    display: table-row-group;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.input {
    display: table-row;
}

.input > * {
    display: table-cell;
}

.input > h4, .input > label {
    padding: 0.5em 0.25em 0 0.5em;
}

.input > select, .input > input {
    margin: 0 0.5em 0.25em 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 0.5em);
}

.input:last-child > * {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.padding {
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="input">
            <h4>Top</h4>
            <div class="empty"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="top-1">Label 1</label>
            <input id="top-1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="top-2">Label 2 is longer than the others</label>
            <input id="top-2"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <div class="padding"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="input">
            <h4>Middle</h4>
            <div class="empty"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="middle-1">Label 3</label>
            <select id="middle-1">
                <option value="middle-value-1">Value 1</option>
                <option value="middle-value-2" selected="selected">This is a longer value</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="middle-2">Label 4</label>
            <input id="middle-2"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <div class="padding"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="input">
            <h4>Bottom</h4>
            <div class="empty"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="bottom-1">Label 5</label>
            <input id="bottom-1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label for="bottom-2">Label 6</label>
            <input id="bottom-2"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your grid up more dynamically with something like this:

```
.inputs {
  width: 33%;
  min-width: 25em;
}

.inputs > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.3fr 1fr;
  gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

I used your outer container to deal with the width as it relates to the screen. The hard `min-width` of 25px keeps the long label from wrapping to another line, instead showing a horizontal scrollbar if the screen size causes 33% of the width to go below 25px.

For your inner containers, you can change the unit in `grid-template-columns` to `fr`, which means fraction of available space. This will let your columns dynamically size along with your window (until you hit the `min-width` for the outer container). You can experiment with the `width` percentage to work out just how much dynamic sizing you would like to do.

[This](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/) is a good writeup of `fr` if you would like one.

Comment: I'm familiar with `fr` units for grids, but I'm not trying to make the grid, nor its columns, some fixed portion of the page width.  What I'd like is for the columns to be wide enough for their content, and no more.  So column 1 should be wide enough to display the longest label, however long it may be (it may be dynamically populated), and column 2 should be wide enough to display the `select` with its longest option chosen.

Comment: @PDaddy Yeah, seems I misunderstood what you were asking for. Glad we haven't burned through millions of dollars already. Anyway, you've found a solution. My feeling is that you could do this in grid with some combination of (the poorly documented) [fit-content()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content) values.